# jquery-mobile css not applied on html generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am getting data from a JSON file and then I display it with an html structure following the jquerymobile structure with data-role, etc...here is my code on how I get the data and display it:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $.getJSON("http://danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/?json=get_posts&post_type=product", function(data){
    var html = "";
        $.each(data.posts, function(index, d){
        html = html + "<li><a href='" + d.slug + "' data-transition='slidedown'><img src='" + d.thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url + "' /><h3 class='ui-li-heading'> Menu" + index + "</h3></a></li>";
        });
        html= "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>"+ html + "</ul>";
        $(html).appendTo(".choice_list");


    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */
        /* alert(jqXHR.responseText) */
        alert("error occurred!");
    });
});
```

The output in HTML is as follws:

```
<li><a href="link1.HTML" data-transition="slidedown"> <img src="source1"><h3> Menu1</h3></a></li>

<li><a href="link2.HTML" data-transition="slidedown"> <img src="source2"><h3> Menu2</h3></a></li>

<li><a href="link3.HTML" data-transition="slidedown"> <img src="source3"><h3> Menu3</h3></a></li>
```

But my problem is that even though I display the content the way jquerymobile says, the style which should be applied is not. I mean all the classes added by jquerymobile script are not added to my html generated with javascript. Anyone kowns how can I fix it? How can I keep the styles from jquerymobile?
Thank you so much in advanced!

**ANSWER:**

```
 $(html).appendTo(".choice_list").listview();
```

Comment: `$('[data-role='listview]').listview('refresh')` after appending the items / outside the loop. in other words, after closing `.error` function.

Comment: Omar, I've tried what you say but then my "<ul>" disappears, it's not even showing. Any ideas?

Comment: try `$('[data-role='listview]').listview().listview('refresh')`

Comment: Nop. It continues to display nothing. I don't understand why...please any hepl would be appreciated. Thank you Omar.

Comment: sorry my bad, place it before `.error`.

Comment: I get a syntax error. Could it be that you forgot to place an apostrophe @Omar?

Comment: And if I add the apostrophe i get the following error: Unexpected identifier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36352/discussion-between-omar-and-ered)

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery mobile docs:

> When the user clicks a link in a jQuery Mobile-driven site, the
>   default behavior of the navigation system is to use that link's href
>   to formulate an Ajax request (instead of allowing the browser's
>   default link behavior of requesting that href with full page load).
>   When that Ajax request goes out, the framework will receive its entire
>   text content, but it will only inject the contents of the response's
>   body element (or more specifically the data-role="page" element, if
>   it's provided), meaning nothing in the head of the page will be used
>   (with the exception of the page title, which is fetched specifically).
>
> This means that any scripts and styles referenced the head of a page
>   won't have any effect when a page is loaded via Ajax, but they will
>   execute if the page is requested normally via HTTP.

[Reference](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

**Create vs. refresh: An important distinction**

> Note that there is an important difference between the create event
>   and refresh method that some widgets have. The create event is suited
>   for enhancing raw markup that contains one or more widgets. The
>   refresh method should be used on existing (already enhanced) widgets
>   that have been manipulated programmatically and need the UI be updated
>   to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with data-role=listview attribute after page creation,
>   triggering create on a parent element of that list would transform it
>   into a listview styled widget. If more list items were then
>   programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method would
>   update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave the
>   existing list items untouched.

You want to `.trigger("create")` after it is loaded.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. `create` is to be used with other widgets, list-view accepts `refresh` method.

Comment: @Omar why the downvote? triggering create is where you, "dynamically appended a new unordered list with data-role=listview attribute after page creation," thus what OP is doing.

Comment: you're referring to old version of jQM. The latest stable version now is 1.3.2. `.listview('refresh')` is the solution. Update your answer with a working answer so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: add `$(html).appendTo('.choice_list').listview().listview('refresh');` or `$(html).appendTo('.choice_list').listview();` as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to call `refresh` on your listview:

```
 $('#myListview').listview('refresh');
```

ref: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-methods.html

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Comment: I've given to my "<ul>" an id and tried to refresh it but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: And you refreshed right after `$(html).appendTo(".choice_list");`?

Comment: Should you be appending `html`? I see you have a myNewStuff variable you aren't using.

Comment: Sorry. The myNewStuff variable is actually the same variable html is. I's already fixed in my question. And yes @Chris Hardie, I've refreshed just after that and now nothing is displayed.

Comment: ok, how about: `$(html).appendTo('.choice_list').listview();`?

Comment: Thank you Chris. Omar gave me the same answer in the chat and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to mark this as the answer if it has helped you!

Comment: How can I mark it as the answer? I just marked your comment as a useful one! But as yours was a comment and not an answer i didn't know how to mark your comment or Omar's as the result so I answered it myself.

Comment: To mark an answer as correct, you need only click the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(html).appendTo(".choice_list").listview();
```